# Can I download early versions of Leela chess zero?

Tags: training, leela, human-versus-machine, chess-ai

I want to play weaker versions of Leela. It would be good to play some really early versions of the net. Is there a repository available where I can download them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For early versions, the lczero project's [download page](http://lczero.org/play/download/) refers you to the [lc0 releases available on GitHub](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/releases). For versions from 2018, you can go the [lczero repository on GitHub](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lczero/releases).

Note that while the downloads from from the former repository (lc0) provide both Windows builds and source code, the older releases from 2018 (lczero) give you only source code that you need to compile by yourself.

Comment: also be warned that there are fairly major bugs in all of the early versions.

Comment: @OscarSmith That might be worth another question. I couldn't find anything about [leela and bugs](https://chess.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bleela%5D+bugs) on this site ;-)